# Storing a reference to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array:

```
const int neoPixelCount = 40;
CRGB neoPixels[neoPixelCount];
```

And I have a `Dancer`, that needs to hold onto a reference of that array. It has an `init` method that looks like this:

```
// .h
class Dancer {
  public:
    CRGB neoPixels[];
    void init(CRGB neoPixels[]);
}

// .cpp
void Dancer::init(CRGB _neoPixels[]) {
  neoPixels = _neoPixels;
}
```

But when I call this, the compiler won't let me pass the reference to array.

```
dancer->init(neoPixels);
```

Which yields:

> discobot/Dancer.cpp: In member function 'void Dancer::init(CRGB*)':
>
> discobot/Dancer.cpp:14: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'CRGB*' to 'CRGB [0]'

What's the right syntax magic to make this work, and why?

Comment: What are you compiling with?

Comment: Um, Arduino? Not sure that's the right answer, but as much as I know at the moment.

Comment: Just having the parameter be a CRGB* instead of a CRGB[] will probably work. That's not really a solution, though, this should work( unless this has an earlier C implementation that doesn't support [], if there is even such a thing. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `CRGB neoPixels[];` to `CRGB* neoPixels;` in the class member declaration, because you want to store a pointer (to the array) rather than a zero/unknown-length array.

Comment: I thought the compiler looked at those two things as identical?

Comment: In a function signature, yes.  As a variable declaration, no.  Sorry, C(++) is a bit complicated.  :)

Comment: @AlexWayne No, arrays are not pointers (and vice versa). Also, if you want an array of things in C++, you'd be better off using `std::vector<CRGB>` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: @user3477950 Or std::array, which would be more appropriate for this situation.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: I did not say a reference to an array is impossible.  I said `CRGB[]` and `CRGB*` are not identical.  We are both correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a reference to an array as a class member your should have something like that

```
class Dancer 
{
public:
    int (&neoPixels)[40]; // reference to an array of 40 elements
    Dancer(int (&neoPixels)[40]) : neoPixels(neoPixels) { }
};
```

The member `neoPixels` is a reference to an array of 40 elements (pardon the change to `int`, it was to do the checks in my machine).

Now since that's a reference it should be initialized in the constructor's initializer list.

To generalize the above idea, your class could be a template holding references to arrays of compile time known sizes.

```
template<size_t N>
class Dancer
{
    public:
    int (&neoPixels)[N]; // reference to an array of N elements
    Dancer(int (&neoPixels)[N]) : neoPixels(neoPixels) { }
};
```

Comment: This answer is correct and should be the accepted answer. This stores a reference to the array. Not just a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing `Dancer` to:

```
class Dancer {
  public:
    CRGB* neoPixels;
    void init(CRGB neoPixels[]);
}
```